# Android Calling Activity from another activity is not working

Tags: android

I am Trying to call an Activity from Default activity but when trigger the call activity my application crashed and closed with this message `07-06 11:54:59.291: E/MapActivity(366): Couldn't get connection factory client`.Here is My Current Code for calling the Activity

```
public class GMapsActivity extends MapActivity {
EditText password;
Button   login;
MapView mapView;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
initcontrols();
}
public void initcontrols()
{
    password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass);
    login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
    mapView=(MapView)findViewById(R.id.map_view);
    login.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
             Intent myIntent = null;
             if(password.getText().toString().equals("admin")) {
             System.out.println("Entering");
             mapView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             login.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
             password.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
             myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), GMapsActivity1.class);

            } else {
            }
             startActivity(myIntent);
        }

    });

}



@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}


}
```

Please anyone help me to do this

**Update**
Here is My 2nd Activity Code Please Check If Any Change Required In this

```
public class GMapsActivity1 extends MapActivity {

private MapView mapView;
EditText password;
Button   login;

JSONArray jArray;
String result = null;
InputStream is = null;
StringBuilder sb=null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);


mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map_view);       
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

 ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
//http post
try{
     HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://sml.com.pk/a/map.php");
     httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
     HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
     HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
     is = entity.getContent();
     }catch(Exception e){
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
    }
//convert response to string
try{
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
       sb = new StringBuilder();
       sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");

       String line="0";
       while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                      sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
              Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }
//paring data
double LAT;
double LANG;
String INFO;
try{
      jArray = new JSONArray(result);
      JSONObject json_data=null;
      for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
             json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
             LAT=json_data.getDouble("lat");
             LANG=json_data.getDouble("lang");
             INFO=json_data.getString("info");


//Overlay code
List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
                Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
        CustomItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);

        //GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(latitudeE6, longitudeE6);
        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(LAT * 1e6),(int)(LANG * 1e6));
        OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Shakarganj", INFO);
        itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

        MapController mapController = mapView.getController();

        mapController.animateTo(point);
        mapController.setZoom(6);

//Overlay code

         }
      }
      catch(JSONException e1){
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Vehicles Found" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}
}
```

Here is My Manifest file Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.javacodegeeks.android.googlemaps"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
      <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

        <activity android:name=".GMapsActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="GMapsActivity1"
           android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </activity>

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />


    </application>    

</manifest>
```

**Update1**

```
package com.javacodegeeks.android.googlemaps;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class CustomItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mapOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

    private Context context;

    public CustomItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
          super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    }

    public CustomItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
          this(defaultMarker);
          this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return mapOverlays.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return mapOverlays.size();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int index) {
        OverlayItem item = mapOverlays.get(index);
        //AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        //dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
        //dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
        //dialog.show();
        //Toast.makeText(context, item.getSnippet(), 20);
        Toast.makeText(context, item.getSnippet(),  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }

    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
        mapOverlays.add(overlay);
        this.populate();
    }

}
```

Comment: 07-06 11:54:59.291: E/MapActivity(366): Couldn't get connection factory client

Comment: Try below answers and Clean your project...

Comment: do you have more than 1 MapActivity in your project?

Comment: Yes One Is GMapsActivity and Other is GMapsActivity1 and I am Calling GMapsActivity1 in GMapsActivity

Comment: Can you post code of your **CustomItemizedOverlay** class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

```
Intent myIntent = null;
if(password.getText().toString().equals("admin")) {
System.out.println("Entering");
mapView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
login.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
password.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
myIntent = new Intent(GMapsActivity.this, GMapsActivity1.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
} else {
Toast.makeText(context, "password is invalid",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
    public class GMapsActivity extends MapActivity {
    EditText password;
    Button   login;
    MapView mapView;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

        password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass);
        login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
        mapView=(MapView)findViewById(R.id.map_view);


        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                 Intent myIntent = null;
                 if(password.getText().toString().equals("admin")) {
                 System.out.println("Entering");
                 mapView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 login.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                 password.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                 myIntent = new Intent(GMapsActivity.this, GMapsActivity1.class);
                 startActivity(myIntent);
                } 

            }

        });

    }



    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }


    }
```

---

**UPDATE**

why you used this:

```
<activity android:name="GMapsActivity1"
          android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

</activity>
```

use like this:

```
<activity
            android:name=".GMapsActivity1" 
            android:launchMode="singleTop" >
</activity>
```

Comment: Sir When I Press Login Then Now it Call the Activity and Map Shows but After 3 seconds it disappears and login text and button become visible

Comment: the above code will start **GMapsActivity1** now if there is problem in that activity then it will crash & u will see the **GMapsActivity** again

Comment: Kindly check My Update And Tell me What is the Issue in My Activity

Comment: Sir Because This was Not Working I copied from Existing Activity

Comment: Sir this is Current Log cat 07-06 12:35:07.672: E/MapActivity(363): Couldn't get connection factory client

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are creating the `myIntent` correct and that it is not null (In the *else* you are not doing anything...)

Also change the create for:

```
myIntent = new Intent(GMapsActivity.this, GMapsActivity1.class);
```

Comment: Sir Still Application is Stopping when I click on login button

Comment: To which class do you want to go in the `else` condition? Make myIntent point to that class in the `else`. Because when you're in the else, myIntent is still `null`.

Comment: Then move your startActivity(myIntent); to the block where the intent is not null...

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(password.getText().toString().equals("admin")) {
             System.out.println("Entering");
             mapView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             login.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
             password.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
             myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), GMapsActivity1.class);

            } else {
            }
             startActivity(myIntent);
```

the above code says myIntent gets initialised only when password is admin and not otherwise.. but its being used even not initialised to start activity..

Comment: So What Should Be Done according to you

Comment: Sir When I Press Login Then Now it Call the Activity and Map Shows but After 3 seconds it disappears and login text and button become visible

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing

```
Intent myIntent = null;
myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), GMapsActivity1.class);
```

Add

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GMapsActivity1.class);
```

or

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(GMapsActivity.this, GMapsActivity1.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this activity inside manifest file else it won't start and it will crash, I think you are not doing this ...

```
 <activity android:name="GMapsActivity1"
           android:launchMode="singleTop"></activity>
```

Comment: Sir When I Press Login Then Now it Call the Activity and Map Shows but After 3 seconds it disappears and login text and button become visible

Answer (score 0):

First put startActivity(myIntent); in if condition and make sure setContentView(...); is properly defined in GMapsActivity1 activity was well as GMapsActivity1 added in manifest file.
One more thing maybe possible i.e you may use R.id.... that is not define in the layout.xml for this activity.

Comment: I Have Updated My Second Activity Please Tell me Where to Set the SetContentView() in that

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but I've found a solution that hasn't yet been posted.

When using calling activities, you must use startActivityForResult for intents that may lead to the activity you are trying to get the calling activity for.

Example:

Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 123);